# opencv perspective transform for a non-rectangle

Tags: opencv

I have a video about 3d printing process, the angle of the camera is as shown in the figure. How can I get the effect of looking down from directly above? The object is also irregularly shaped, I only know what to do if it is a rectangle. Any hints?
[image]

Comment: "homography". the top layer, assuming that is the top layer, is a plane.

Comment: You can always generate a bounding box for a contour. Then you can apply a regular transform, as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179164/opencv-image-transformation-and-perspective-change?rq=2